# multiple checkbox alignement

Tags: html, css

I would like to fix the position of multiple checkboxes. I would like the first checkbox at the coordinates X=340 Y=250.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="checkboxes">Select which contacts to display :
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="foreach: viewModel.mailAddresses() ">
                <label for="CheckBoxOne">
                    <input id="CheckBoxOne" type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: viewModel.ui.CheckedEmails" /> <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="foreach: viewModel.ui.Options() ">
                <label for="CheckBoxTwo">
                    <input id="CheckBoxTwo" type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: viewModel.ui.CheckedOptions" /> <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
.checkboxes label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.checkboxes input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.checkboxes label span {
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Screenshot without vertical align with Select message:

[image: screenshot]

Screenshot of what I'm looking for :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: tables are for tabular data - not layout

Comment: why are you specific about the co-ordinates? is there a reason for it? also can we have a look at the rest of your CSS and HTML? can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: no matter for the co-ordinate, I just want to have my checkboxes vertical align with my Select message (I'm using knockout, my js is very long that'why I didn't create a jsfiddle

Comment: ok, that is one problem out of the way. coming to the vertical align, I created [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/RmRSz/) based on the code you have posted and it seems fine. That is the reason why I asked for the rest of it. If fiddle is not possible, can you put the code elsewhere for us to see?

Comment: Thx for help, I solved my issue ! I checked my CSS code and I forget to remove a margin auto (table) ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning for exact coordinates:

```
position:absolute;
left:340px;
top:250px;
```

Be aware that absolute positioning is not reliable cross browser though.

Comment: thx but I don't want break my positioning if user reduces window view

Comment: @user2613813 responsive? please explain further

Comment: edited sry : thx but I don't want break my positioning if user reduces window view